# How to solve AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower in scipy minimize

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to use scipy minimize to find the best values for r,p,K and alpha

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(Y,t,params):
    r, p, K, alpha = params
    return r * (Y ** p) * (1 - (Y / K) ** alpha)

t = np.linspace(0, len(df), len(df))
y0=1
initial_guess = [0.5, 0.5, 200000,0.7]

# result = minimize(f,initial_guess) #I used this one first but I got an error (TypeError: f() missing 2 required positional arguments: 't' and 'params') so I changed this one to the one below (I added y0 and t)

result = minimize(f, y0,t,initial_guess)
```

However this returns an error **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'**, below is the entire error I received

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-2930fc38c1cc> in <module>()
      9 initial_guess = [0.5, 0.5, 200000,0.7]
     10 
---> 11 result = minimize(f, y0,t,initial_guess)

/home/lenovo/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    496         meth = "_custom"
    497     else:
--> 498         meth = method.lower()
    499 
    500     if options is None:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

**How can I solve this error?**

Comment: According to the documentation, the definition of `f` is supposed to be `fun(x, *args)`.  I think that's why you had an error when you tried `minimize(f, initial_guess)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=(), method=None, jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, constraints=(), tol=None, callback=None, options=None)[source]

minimize(f, y0,t,initial_guess)
```

pairing args

```
fun -- f
x0  -- y0
args -- t
method -- initial_guess        # problem
```

You provide a list of numbers as the `method` parameter!

Your `fun` is supposed to have the signature: `fun(x, *args)`.  The `x` will be an array/number that is initially `x0`.  This what `minimize` varies when searching. `args` is supposed to be a tuple (people often get this wrong).  `minimize` just passes these through; it does not vary them.

I don't understand what roles you intend `y0`, `t` and `initial_guess` to play.  And I suspect you don't either.